# UNITY: Is it possible to access the GameObject that a PropertyAttribute is attached to?

Tags: attributes, unity-game-engine

For example if I create a PropertyAttribute;

```
ExampleAttribute : PropertyAttribute { etc...
```

and a respective PropertyDrawer

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof(ExampleAttribute))]
public class ExampleDrawer : PropertyDrawer
```

Is it possible to talk to the Monobehaviour script that has invoked the *[Example]* attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Unity calls your property drawer's [OnGUI](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.OnGUI.html), it'll pass a [SerializedProperty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html). The property's [serializedObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty-serializedObject.html) is the SerializedObject that owns it.

You didn't specify what you wanted to *do* with that object, but now you have a reference to it:

```
public void OnGUI(Rect rect, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
    //do other GUI stuff
    Debug.Log("I belong to " + property.serializedObject.targetObject, this);
}
```